# Updating values in a specific column based on values in another column

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Sorry for the trivial question.

I am having troubles with selecting and replacing a value in list based on the values in another column. I have the following list:

```
Jack     0.794938   0
Marc     0.05155265 0
Eliza    0.96454115 0
Louis    0.075102   0
Milo     0.951499   0
Marc     0.63319    0
Michael  0.719391   0
Louis    0.502843   0
Eliza    0.620387   0
```

I would like to keep the first occurrence of each name with the third column taking the value of the second column of the second occurrence. So the result should be:

```
Jack     0.794938   0
Marc     0.05155265 0.63319
Eliza    0.96454115 0.620387
Louis    0.075102   0.502843
Milo     0.951499   0
Michael  0.719391   0
```

I am using this code:

```
res = []
already_added = set()
for e in a:
    key1 = e[0]
if key1 not in already_added:
    res.append(e)
```

from that point on I would like something like:

```
else:
        res[res[:][0] == e[0]][2] = e[1]
```

or

```
else:
        res[np.where(res[:][0] == e[0]][2])] = e[1]
```

But I keep getting the TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.
Can someone help me solve this?

Thanks

Edit: I corrected the indices

Comment: This is confusing.  The title says `list`.  The tag is `numpy`.  The list display looks like a `pandas` table, as does the name in your code `df`.  `res` is clearly a list.  `np.where` creates a tuple of arrays (possibly empty).  As the error says, you can't index a list with a list (or tuple).  That's basic Python.

Comment: I changed the name of the table to a, which is an numpy.ndarray; sorry for the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure numpy solution. It sorts the records by first column to easily find duplicate names.

```
import numpy as np


data = """
Jack     0.794938   0
Marc     0.05155265 0
Eliza    0.96454115 0
Louis    0.075102   0
Milo     0.951499   0
Marc     0.63319    0
Michael  0.719391   0
Louis    0.502843   0
Eliza    0.620387   0
"""

data = (line.split() for line in data.strip().split('\n'))
data = np.array([(x, float(y), float(z)) for x, y, z in data], dtype=object)

res = data.copy()
idx = np.argsort(res[:, 0], kind='mergesort')
dupl = res[idx[:-1], 0] == res[idx[1:], 0]
res[idx[:-1][dupl], 2] = res[idx[1:][dupl], 1]
mask = np.ones(res.shape[:1], dtype=bool)
mask[idx[1:][dupl]] = False
res = res[mask]
```

Result:

```
# array([['Jack', 0.794938, 0.0],
#        ['Marc', 0.05155265, 0.63319],
#        ['Eliza', 0.96454115, 0.620387],
#        ['Louis', 0.075102, 0.502843],
#        ['Milo', 0.951499, 0.0],
#        ['Michael', 0.719391, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas:
Load values into a dataframe, df:

```
csvfile = StringIO("""Jack     0.794938   0
Marc     0.05155265  0
Eliza    0.96454115  0
Louis    0.075102    0
Milo     0.951499    0
Marc     0.63319     0
Michael  0.719391    0
Louis    0.502843    0
Eliza    0.620387    0""")

df= pd.read_csv(csvfile, header=None, sep='\s\s+')
```

Then, use `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
df.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[1].tolist()))\
  .unstack().add_prefix('value').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         0    value0    value1
0    Eliza  0.964541  0.620387
1     Jack  0.794938       NaN
2    Louis  0.075102  0.502843
3     Marc  0.051553  0.633190
4  Michael  0.719391       NaN
5     Milo  0.951499       NaN
```